# How to list directory content of remote FTP, recursively

Tags: ftp

After downloading files from a remote UNIX FTP server, you want to verify that you have downloaded all the files correctly. Minimal you will get information similar to "dir /s" command in Windows command prompt. The FTP client runs on Windows.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sadly this was written for Unix/Linux users :/

Personally, I would install CYGWIN just to get Linux binaries of LFTP/RSYNC to work on windows, as there appears not to be anything that competes with it.

As @zadok.myopenid.com 
mentioned rsync, this appears to be a windows build for it using CYGWIN ( if you manage to be able to get ssh access to the box eventually )

http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

Rsync is handy in that it will compare everything with check sums, and optimally transfer partial change blocks.

---

If you get CYGWIN/Linux:

http://lftp.yar.ru/   is my favorite exploration tool for this.

It can do almost everything bash can do, albeit remotely.

Example:

```
$ lftp mirror.3fl.net.au
lftp mirror.3fl.net.au:~> ls                          
drwxr-xr-x  14 root     root         4096 Nov 27  2007 games
drwx------   2 root     root        16384 Apr 13  2006 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  15 mirror   mirror       4096 Jul 15 05:20 pub
lftp mirror.3fl.net.au:/> cd games/misc
lftp mirror.3fl.net.au:/games/misc>find
./
./dreamchess/
./dreamchess/full_game/                                                      
./dreamchess/full_game/dreamchess-0.2.0-win32.exe                                      
./frets_on_fire/
./frets_on_fire/full_game/                                                      
./frets_on_fire/full_game/FretsOnFire-1.2.451-macosx.zip                                  
./frets_on_fire/full_game/FretsOnFire-1.2.512-win32.zip
./frets_on_fire/full_game/FretsOnFire_ghc_mod.zip
./gametap_setup.exe
......
lftp mirror.3fl.net.au:/games/misc> du gametap_setup.exe 
32442   gametap_setup.exe
lftp mirror.3fl.net.au:/games/misc> du -sh gametap_setup.exe 
32M     gametap_setup.exe
lftp mirror.3fl.net.au:/games/misc>
```

Comment: If you want to automate this:
`lftp -u user,password -e 'find /;bye' host > file_list`
or to just get a count of files
`lftp -u user,password -e 'find /;bye' host | -wc -l`

Comment: To get more details, you can also add the `-l` option to `find` in `lftp`: `find -l` and add an optional directory name.

Answer (score 7):

Do this :

```
ls -lR
```

..................

Comment: +1, but apparently there is a typo: `ls -R` is working well, while the `1` seems wrong (it removes info from the list and doesn't recurse anymore)

Comment: I presume you want `ls -lR` (the letter l, not a 1)

Answer (score 4):

If you have ssh access, use rsync instead.  It is a far better data transfer app.

Grab fuse for your OS and load ftpfs.  This will let you mount the remote ftp directory locally and you can use dir /s or any other application you want on it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using simple ftp via command line, 
Use dir command with -Rl option to search recursively and copy it to a file and then search the file using grep, find or whatever way is supported on your OS.

ftp> dir -Rl education.txt
output to local-file: education.txt? y
227 Entering Passive Mode (9,62,119,15,138,239)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
226 Transfer complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ftp.listFiles("directory")** from apache-commons-net and can write your own BFS or DFS to fetch all the files recursively.