# Getting a list of files recursively using SFTP in shell or Python with no additional libraries

Tags: python, linux, shell, sftp

I am transferring files between two servers via SFTP using python's subprocess module. The only way I can connect to the remote server is via an SFTP connection.

I need to verify that the two directories on the local and remote server are identical after the transfer. This is pretty easy on the local server, a basic find command gives me what I need. However I have no clue how to get a similar result on the remote server.

Here's an example of the file structure, its identical on both machines.

```
JobDirectory
    Job1
        test.txt
        tonks.txt
    Job2
        wildlife.txt
    Job3
        jackinthebox.txt
        happygilmore.txt
        sadprogrammer.txt
```

So I need a command that'll get the filenames from `Job1`, `Job2`, and `Job3` and return them to me.

Something like

```
echo "ls *.txt" | sftp -q user@host.example.com:/path
```

doesn't track too well here, since it needs a specific path. I could get a list of folders within the directory and run the `sftp` command against each of them, but that's a lot of remote connections.

The only remote access tools I can use are subprocess and Python's OS module. Something like Paramiko SFTP is not available.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, this answer doesn't really meet my requirements. The first will open an SFTP connection for every directory and is written in bash, the 2nd uses a tool I do not have access too

Comment: Who removed the other comments/posts here? They were useful and I was looking into their suggestions

Comment: For the deleted comments and answer: All were deleted by their respective owners, once they have realized that they are wrong. -- So no, they were definitely *not* useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an easy but inefficient solution, see the answer by @pasabaporaqui to [List recursively all files on sftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30504124/850848#30509562).

---

With your obscure limitation, the only solution that uses one connection would be:

- open an `sftp` subprocess in Python
- feed sequence of `ls` commands to it, one for each directory
- parsing the directory listings coming on standard output, producing more `ls` commands for each subdirectory found.